# Is "for(;;)" faster than "while (true)"? If not, why do people use it?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, readability, infinite-loop

```
for (;;) {
    //Something to be done repeatedly
}
```

I have seen this sort of thing used a lot, but I think it is rather strange...
Wouldn't it be much clearer to say `while(true)`, or something along those lines?

I'm guessing that (as is the reason for many-a-programmer to resort to cryptic code) this is a tiny margin faster?

Why, and is it *really* worth it? If so, why not just define it this way:

```
#define while(true) for(;;)
```

#### See also: [Which is faster: while(1) or while(2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848359/which-is-faster-while1-or-while2)

Comment: What is `TRUE`???

Comment: TRUE is 1, TRUE is a define of win32 afaik

Comment: @smerlin: Could be. But what is it doing in a question that has no mention of Win32 whatsoever?

Comment: If this is C++, then use `true`.  For C, use `TRUE`.  That's all.

Comment: I was assuming TRUE to be defined to 1 for use as a pseudo-boolean value.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: What does `TRUE` have to do with C? The standard macro for true boolen result in C99 is still `true`. Where did the `TRUE` come from?

Comment: I personally find `for(;;)` to be the clearer construct.  `while (true)` implies you're testing `true` every loop; obviously I know this is optimized away, but it's unnecessary code.

Comment: That macro doesn't work, `#define EVER ;;` has been used in IOCCC though.. :)

Comment: I was just thinking the phrase "infinite loop" is kind of misleading, because really we don't mean infinite as there is still a condition that the loop breaks.  Instead we mean it is a "loop that has complex conditions beyond the capability of the language's built-in constructs to support looping".  It's just that the condition is not necessarily an expression, but might be an event or something of that sort.

Comment: Some header included by <windows.h> defines TRUE for the Windows BOOL type. That's probably where this comes from. It's really common in win32 programming.

Comment: just don't write for(;;); or you might get into some trouble

Comment: Isn't that macro for `#define while(TRUE)` declaring a macro that takes one argument called `TRUE` that is never used, therefore turning every single while loop in your program in to an infinite loop?

Comment: @Andrey: The standard macro in VS 6.0 is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: No. There's no "standard macro in VS 6.0". Macro `TRUE` comes from header files associated with Windows API. It is not related to VS 6.0 in any way. And, as I said before, it has nothing to do with either C or C++. In C++ the "true" literal is just `true` (in VS 6.0 as well), in C89/90 there's no such thing at all, and in C99 it is macro `true`. This applies to all C/C++ compilers.

Comment: @AndreyT: I think you're trying to be pickier than is useful. VS 6.0 does come with the Windows SDK header files, which are included with StdAfx.h in a default project.  This header has a `TRUE` #define.  This #define has been around in the C Windows SDK for some time, predating the addition of `true` to the language, which is why I referred to it as being C++ but not C.  Now that I've explained myself, I'm really not interested in quibbling past this point.

Comment: The point though: it's non-portable...

Comment: @Steven: There is no TRUE, simple as that.

Comment: @anon Just use `while(1)` then, although I am sure you were not [born an eagle](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: I see some people use 'goto' for infinite loop. Is 'goto' fastest?

Comment: @GManNickG: you can't handle the TRUE. All non-Windows users, that is.

Comment: So actually someone asked if `for (;;)` is ***faster*** (???) than `while (1)`. Faith in the programmer community lost, once again.

Comment: No one has pointed out: `for(;;)` is only 7 characters where `while(true)` is 11, even `while(1)` is 8.  So from a Rabid Application Development standpoint we should all be using `for` clearly.  Especially when `;;` makes use of valuable home-row real-estate normally squandered by QWERTY.

Comment: Actually `#define EVER ;;` has *never* been used in the IOCCC, at least not in a winning entry. When I was first learning C, I did use `#define EVER ;;`, or perhaps `#define EVER (;;)`. At the time, I thought it was very clever. I still think it's very clever; I just no longer thing that's a good thing.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

1. It's not faster.
2. If you really care, compile with assembler output for your platform and look to see.
3. It doesn't matter. This never matters. Write your infinite loops however you like.

Comment: Intuitively, optimizing an infinite loop offers the potential for infinite speed-up.  Good thing we don't program on intuition, then. :-)

Comment: It did matter, since some early compilers on some platforms did load a constant and made a conditional jump of it. Which on those days hardware, did matter.

Comment: It matters to humans. [Why you shouldn't write while(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24879856/830749)

Comment: I use for(;;) as while(true) will generate a warning about a constant conditional expression.

Answer (score 199):

I prefer `for(;;)` for two reasons.

One is that some compilers produce warnings on `while(true)` (something like "loop condition is constant"). Avoiding warnings is always a good thing to do.

Another is that I think `for(;;)` is clearer and more telling.
I want an infinite loop. It literally *has* no condition, it depends on nothing. I just want it to continue forever, until I do something to break out of it.

Whereas with `while(true)`, well, what's true got to do with anything? I'm not interested in looping until true becomes false, which is what this form literally says (loop while true is true). I just want to loop.

And no, there is absolutely no performance difference.

Comment: +1 for avoiding warnings.  But as for clarity, I find while clearer than for in this context.  I guess that aspect just comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Yep, preferance and habit. If you're not used to seeing `for(;;)`, it'll obviously look strange. But I'd recommend trying to get used to it because it *is* a common idiom, and you're going to run into it again. ;)

Comment: I'm sure I'll run into again, but that doesn't mean it's a good practice =P. I agree with Tim that "while" is more telling, because "for" is usually used when you want to do something a specifiably number of times. As Jalf said, "for(;;)" has NO condition. why is no condition the same as a new condition? If I said "do this under no condition", it means NEVER DO THIS. Anyway, that's just my take. =)

Comment: It has no condition: It is an unconditional loop. And I do want to do something a "specified number of times". That number is just infinity.
How is `while` better? You usually use that *until* the condition changes. And that's never gonna happen.

I don't care about whether 1==1, or 42>0 or TRUE evaluates to true. All of those are just roundabout ways of saying "keep doing this". All of them *could* be placed in a `while` loop to achieve the same thing. But when we already have a specific loop form for this, why jump through all those hoops?

Comment: @jalf: is there any circumstance under which you would use a `while(condition)` loop, given that `for(;condition;)` does the same thing? In defence of `while(true)`, it explicitly states "the continuation condition always holds", i.e. "always continue". `for(;;)` implicitly says the same thing because of a special language rule that omitting the condition means always continue. Logically it could just as easily have meant always break, but of course loop-zero-times is a lot less useful than loop-forever. Or not been allowed at all. So it's a "special idiom" whichever you use.

Comment: To declare my interest, I usually write `while(true)`, but I don't think either is any more clear or readable or simple than the other, since they are both utterly clear. What I *want* to write is `loop { ... }`, or maybe `{ ... ; continue; }`, but never mind. I'd be inclined to avoid anything which leads to statements like "I am doing this a number of times equal to infinity", because I have a degree in maths, and that's just painful ;-)

Comment: jalf's comment about it being idiomatic is really the answer here.  It's commonly used for "infinite loop" simply because it *is* the commonly used way of writing "infinite loop" in C.  There doesn't have to be a good reason for an idiom - it's just a self-reinforcing convention.

Comment: @caf: good point. Code monkey see, code monkey do. Still, it's reassuring that jalf also sees advantages beyond just familiarity :-)

Comment: Cultural conventions are important though - they allow us to communicate more effectively.

Comment: @Steve: I don't see why I'd *ever* use `for(;condition;)`. That is what a while loop is *for*. But like I said, with an infinite loop, I don't really want the compiler to compare *any* condition. Naively, with a `while` loop, it'd have to test `true` every iteration (obviously, not even the dumbest compiler would do that, but it's the principle that bothers me. It strikes me as overspecifying your code), while with a `for(;;)` you are literally saying "there is no condition to test. Just loop". I find it the closest equivalent to your imaginary `loop {...}`

Comment: But, just so we're clear, this isn't something I feel strongly about. I have absolutely no problem seeing `while(true)` in code I have to work with, and I think both are perfectly readable. I'm just explaining why *I* think `for(;;)` is preferable.

Comment: Fair enough. I just asked because you said "we already have a specific loop form for this", so I was wondering whether you're taking the same view as Go, that "for" is all we need. Evidently not :-)

Comment: They haven't actually removed anything other than do...while, just conflated it. All the "parameters" to `for` are optional, so in Go an infinite loop is `for { ... }`. `for <condition> { ... }` is equivalent to a while loop, there's a normal three-clause for loop, and finally `for i := range <sequence> { ... }` is a foreach loop. Makes sense, although I've only used Go a little, so it's still doing my head in that the same keyword is used for everything ;-)

Comment: Your compiler sucks if `while(true)` gives a warning.

Comment: @Albert: Microsoft Visual C++ developers seem to not share your opinion.

Comment: I don't quite know why, but to me `for(;;)` succinctly represents the quintessential badness of C (and C++, by inheritance). More so than the terrible treatment of arrays, even more so than the low regard for numerical programming, and even more so than the ~14 pages of summarized undefined behavior in the C standard, and much worse, the "we're so embarrassed by the huge amount of UB that exists in C++ that we won't even summarize it in an appendix" in the C++ standard.

Comment: My experience is that answers containing `for(;;)` get downvoted on Stack Overflow in cases where the same answer with `while(true)` would earn upvotes.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I suppose I'll have to go downvote some `while(true)` questions then... ;-)

Answer (score 59):

Personally I use `for (;;)` because there aren't any numbers in it, it's just a keyword. I prefer it to `while (true)`, `while (1)`, `while (42)`, `while (!0)` etc etc.

Comment: 0, 1, and infinity are acceptable magic numbers, extending 0 and 1 to false and true isn't a loss.  `true` is no more a magic number than `for` is a magic keyword or that `for(;;)` uses an implied magic infinity.  (`while (42)` is indeed an abomination.)

Comment: Tangent: one of my CS professors said "there are only three numbers in programming: 0, 1, and n. anything else is called a magic number."

Comment: Except for in VB, where true cast to an integer gives -1.

Comment: while(42) is the coolest, produces no different result with respect to while(1) or while(true) or while(!0), and has _philosophical_ meaning. I suppose `for(;;)` is parsed faster than the others anyway

Comment: @ShinTakezou much better to `#define LIFE 42` `while (LIFE)` :)

Comment: well `while(true)` doesn't contain any number too. and for(;;) is not a keyword

Comment: @RiaD Parse the phrase as *just one keyword*.

Comment: What about `for(0xEFAAAAAA)`?

Answer (score 57):

**Because of Dennis Ritchie**

- I started using `for (;;)` because that's the way Dennis Ritchie does it in K&R, and when learning a new language I always try to imitate the smart guys.
- This is  idiomatic C/C++.  It's probably better in the long run to get used to it if you plan on doing much in the C/C++ space.
- Your `#define` won't work, since the thing being #define'd has to look like a C identifier.
- All modern compilers will generate the same code for the two constructs.

Comment: Yes, this is how you know that someone learned C from K&R, the way it should be learned.  Whenever I see `while(TRUE)`, I suspect the programmer is a C newbie, or learned C from a For Dummies book.

Comment: I hear those newbies use [newfangled function definition style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092074/1011250) too.

Comment: IIRC, under Ritchie's original C compiler, `for(;;)` did generate less code than `while(1)`, and was therefore preferred (since they cared *a lot* about code size in those days).

Answer (score 52):

I prefer `for (;;)` because it's the most consistent in different C-like languages.

In C++ `while (true)` is fine, but in C you depend on a header to define `true`, yet `TRUE` is a commonly used macro too. If you use `while (1)` it's correct in C and C++, and JavaScript, but not Java or C#, which require the loop condition to be a boolean, such as `while (true)` or `while (1 == 1)`. In PHP, keywords are case-insensitive but the language prefers the capitalization `TRUE`.

However, `for (;;)` is always completely correct in all of those languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this is actually the first answer that shows an **objective** way that `for (;;)` is better.

Comment: I don't think I've ever need to write code that's correct in C, C++, JavaScript, Java, and C#. They're different languages.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's not  about write code that is correct in many languages; i think it is about avoiding misinterpretation between developers with different backgrounds.

Comment: @sam: Both `while (1)` and `for (;;)` are common idioms for infinite loops in C. Anyone reading a C program who has trouble understanding either will likely have trouble with the rest of the code. It's not worthwhile to write C code that can be easily read by someone who doesn't know C.

Comment: @KeithThompson While a competent reader of C should definitely be familiar with both idioms, this could also be useful if the writer is a polyglot programmer. At my last job I worked in JS, ActionScript, and PHP on a daily basis, and unifying the way one writes code (where it makes sense to do so) can make programming faster and maintenance easier.

Comment: This is a great reason to switch to `for`, as I've been burned by the very things in this post.

Comment: Update on "it's the most consistent in different C-like languages": in Kotlin, you can't write `for (;;)` - it's a syntax error - but instead the normal way you write an infinite loop in Kotlin is `while (true)`. Which is unfortunate, because I like using `for (;;)`.

Answer (score 48):

It's certainly not faster in any sane compiler.  They will both be compiled into unconditional jumps.  The for version is easier to type (as Neil said) and will be clear if you understand for loop syntax.

If you're curious, here is what gcc 4.4.1 gives me for x86.  Both use the x86 [JMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_%28x86_instruction%29) instruction.

```
void while_infinite()
{
    while(1)
    {
    puts("while");
    }
}

void for_infinite()
{
    for(;;)
    {
    puts("for");
    }
}
```

compiles to (in part):

```
.LC0:
.string "while"
.text
.globl while_infinite
    .type   while_infinite, @function
while_infinite:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
.L2:
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    puts
    jmp .L2
    .size   while_infinite, .-while_infinite
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "for"
    .text
.globl for_infinite
    .type   for_infinite, @function
for_infinite:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
.L5:
    movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    puts
    jmp .L5
    .size   for_infinite, .-for_infinite
```

Comment: I doubt it's faster even in debug mode.

Comment: `for_infinite` is faster; 2 fewer characters to `puts`.

Comment: It is technically true: Printing a shorter string is always faster than printing a longer string. There's no magic: `puts` must iterate from the string pointer's starting address through each memory location until it reaches the null character. More characters means more loop iterations, which means slower execution time. In practice, they'd have virtually identical run times. My comment was tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 22):

I personally prefer the `for (;;)` idiom (which will compile to the same code as `while (TRUE)`.

Using `while (TRUE)` may be more readable in one sense, I've decided to use the `for (;;)` idiom because **it stands out**.

An infinite loop construct should be easily noticed or called out in code, and I personally think the `for (;;)` style does this a bit better than `while (TRUE)` or `while (1)`.

Also, I recall that some compilers issue warnings when the controlling expression of a while loop is a constant. I don't think that happens too much, but just the potential for spurious warnings is enough for me to want to avoid it.

Answer (score 18):

I've seen some people prefer it because they have a #define somewhere like this:

```
#define EVER ;;
```

Which allows them to write this:

```
for (EVER)
{
    /* blah */
}
```

Comment: I've seen that too; but it is not a good reason for preferring it. As a maintainer, you'd still have to check the macro definition to be certain that it did what you'd expect, whereas the original code was clear enough. The RTOS VxWorks has a macro `FOREVER` defined `for(;;)`, but that is no better.  IMO macros should not be used to 'invent' a new language.

Comment: Actually the purpose of macros in some languages is to invent new syntax.  But regardless 'for (EVER)' in C/C++ is heinous.

Answer (score 16):

What about (if your language supports it):

```
start:
/* BLAH */
goto start;
```

Comment: ...which should generate identical output in the hands of any reasonable compiler.

Comment: +1 !  It doesn't ameliorate `goto`'s numerous disadvantages but, if the algorithm you're trying to implement comes from a flow-chart, this is the most direct translation.

Comment: I personally take a utilitarian view about goto. There are no raptors. The raptors are people. And it was people who started using goto to make spaghetti code.  Also, assembled output for a loop looks pretty much just like this. The instruction sets for computers don't have concepts of "for" or "while", just "jump".

Comment: never ever ever use `goto`

Comment: The really nice thing about `goto` is you don't have to worry about someone adding a `break` to make your loop less infinite.  (unless you're already inside another `while` or `for` loop of course...)

Answer (score 14):

There's no difference in terms of the machine code that is generated.

However, just to buck the trend, I'd argue that the while(TRUE) form is much more readable and intuitive than for(;;), and that readability and clarity are much more important reasons for coding guidelines than any reasons I've heard for the for(;;) approach (I prefer to base my coding guidelines on solid reasoning and/or proof of effectiveness myself).

Comment: That depends on your language. `for(;;)` is the traditional way to do this in C and C++. `while(true)` seems to be the convention in C# and Java and other languages. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: But someone that is not very familiar with C or C++ will read while(true) more easily and someone familiar with them will understand it as well, therefore is more readable.

Comment: Yes, and somebody who is not very familiar with C or C++ might find STRING_SCAN_FORMATTED more readable than sscanf, but you don't see anyone putting #define STRING_SCAN_FORMATTED sscanf at the top of their code.

Comment: I'd say the idiomatic way of doing it *had better* be the most readable to your developer. Otherwise you really need better developers.

Comment: @despart: If somebody is not familiar enough with C++ to recognize that idiom for what it is, then they need to stay the hell away from my codebase.

Comment: I agree that the idiomatic way ought to be the most readable. Which is why the idiomatic ways always need to be challenged and changed as languages and practices evolve. It took years for the terrible K&R "idiomatic" coding style to be replaced by the modern, more readable style, but it still happened.

Answer (score 13):

```
while(true)
```

generates a warning with Visual Studio (condition is constant).  Most places I've worked compile production builds with warnings as errors.  So

```
for(;;)
```

is preferred.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using? With 2008 I don't get this warning, even at warning level 4.

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson:  The warning definitely fired in VS 2008 at warning level 4, though many library headers disable this warning or drop the level back down to 3, so you might not have seen it.  In 2015, MSVC stopped generating the warning on certain trivial expressions, like `while (true)`, but still does it for other inputs like `while (42)`.  Today, the documentation still suggests using `for (;;)` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4127

Comment: Darn, that was more than a decade ago! :D These days, it's either C with gcc or C#. C# doesn't complain about `while (true)` because of type system. In C, I try to use a valid condition in the loop. I often start out with a `while (<non-zero>)` if the condition isn't clear to me yet.

Answer (score 11):

Not just a well-known pattern, but a standard idiom in C (and C++)

Comment: Yes, and I think some compilers warn on `while (true)` for the same reason they do on `if (true)`.

Answer (score 11):

Both should be same if your code is optimized by compiler. To explain what I mean by optimization, here is a sample code written in MSVC 10:

```
int x = 0;

while(true) // for(;;)
{
    x +=1;

    printf("%d", x);
}
```

If you build it in Debug mode (**without any optimization (/Od)**) disassembly shows the clear difference. There is extra instructions for the `true` condition inside `while`.

```
while(true)
00D313A5  mov         eax,1                //extra 
00D313AA  test        eax,eax              //extra
00D313AC  je          main+39h (0D313B9h)  //extra
    {
        x +=1;
00D313AE  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00D313B1  add         eax,1  
00D313B4  mov         dword ptr [x],eax  
    printf("%d", x);
    ...
    }
00D313B7  jmp         main+25h (0D313A5h)  


for(;;)
    {
        x +=1;
00D213A5  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00D213A8  add         eax,1  
00D213AB  mov         dword ptr [x],eax  
    printf("%d", x);
    ...
    }
00D213AE  jmp         main+25h (0D213A5h)
```

However, if you build your code in Release mode (with default **Maximize Speed (/O2)**) you get same output for both. Both loops are reduced to one jump instruction.

```
for(;;)
    {
        x +=1;
01291010  inc         esi  

        printf("%d", x);
    ...
    }
0129101C  jmp         main+10h (1291010h)  

    while(true)
    {
        x +=1;
00311010  inc         esi  

        printf("%d", x);
    ...
    }
0031101C  jmp         main+10h (311010h)
```

Whichever you will use does not matter for a decent compiler with speed optimization is on.

Comment: This is actually a very good point!  Without optimization even modern compilers will differ by several instructions.

Answer (score 10):

It's a matter of personal preference which way is faster.  Personally, I am a touchtypist and never look at my keyboard, during programming -- I can touchtype all 104 keys on my keyboard.

I find if faster to type "while (TRUE)".

I mentally added some finger movement measurements and totalled them up.
"for(;;)" has about 12 key-widths of movements back and fourth (between home keys and the keys, and between home keys and SHIFT key)
"while (TRUE)" has about 14 key-widths of movements back and fourth.

However, I am vastly less error-prone when typing the latter.  I mentally think in words at a time, so I find it faster to type things like "nIndex" than acronyms such as "nIdx" because I have to actually mentally spell out the lettering rather than speak it inside my mind and let my fingers auto-type the word (like riding a bicycle)

(My TypingTest.com benchmark = 136 WPM)

Comment: I believe the OP was referring to runtime speed, not typing speed.

Comment: I know.  Just had to cover that base, too.

Comment: s/personal preference/individual habit/

Comment: @SamB: Comment up-vote for s///. xD
And yes, although I suggested it may be be due to runtime speed, I didn't know the actual answer. If this was it, I would have been happy.

Comment: Run `time head -10 >/dev/null`, type each 10 times, and measure the results. I bet you'll be faster at `for(;;)` unless you cheat. I was by about 14%.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot imagine that a worthwhile compiler would generate any different code. Even if it did, there would be no way of determining without testing the particular compiler which was more efficient.

However I suggest you prefer `for(;;)` for the following reasons:

- a number of compilers I have used will generate a constant expression warning for while(true) with appropriate warning level settings.
- in your example the macro TRUE may not be defined as you expect
- there are many possible variants of the infinite while loop such as `while(1)`, `while(true)`, `while(1==1)` etc.; so `for(;;)` is likely to result in greater consistency.

Comment: TRUE may not be #define TRUE 1, but any code base in which `while(TRUE)` evaluates as `while(0)` is not likely to benefit from `for(;;)`.

Comment: @Justin : I agree, it would be truly perverse, and it is not the strongest of the three arguments, but Bjarne Stoustrup uses a similar argument for avoiding the NULL macro in C++. `while(true)` should be preferred in any case.  In C++ `bool` is reserved, and in C defined in C stdbool.h (making it less safe in C). `for(;;)` removes all doubt.

Answer (score 5):

All good answers - behavior should be exactly the same.

HOWEVER - Just suppose it DID make a difference. Suppose one of them took 3 more instructions per iteration.

Should you care?

ONLY if what you do inside the loop is *almost nothing*, which is *almost never* the case.

My point is, there is micro-optimization and macro-optimization. Micro-optimization is like "getting a haircut to lose weight".

Comment: How frequently do you see people told to prefer `++i` over `i++`?

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: The difference between `++i` and `i++` can potentially be significant if `i` is an instance of a class rather than a built-in and the compiler does not apply the trivial optimisation. The advice is to acquire a habit so that it won't catch you out when it counts.

Comment: The thing about `++i` vs `i++` is that it doesn't cost you anything to make the "optimization". True, in most cases it makes absolutely no difference, but they're equally easy to type, so why not prefer the potentially most efficient by default? And I suppose the same applies here. If one *was* a tiny bit faster than the other, why *not* go for the faster one? What would we lose by doing it? Both are fairly easy to read and type out.

Comment: @Clifford: @jalf: I am trying to lose weight :-), and I do get haircuts, but arguments of the form: "You would save a micro-cent so why not do it?" don't impress me much, because it only takes a micro-reason to ignore it, such as "The sun is shining, so why think about it?"

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: You're right. I see that a lot on SO, and Clifford's comment is right. In addition, there's something I **don't** see a lot on SO, and that is how to do macro-optimization, like a 43x speedup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773. So I wonder about our priorities.

Comment: @Clifford: While I understand your point completely (and as a pilot, that kind of reasoning is essential), in programming I always have to get down to specifics. For example, in the few cases I've seen where swapping the `++` and the `i` made a significant change in performance bacause `i` was a class instance, it made a *much larger* change in performance to replace `i` by an integer. "Can't always do that" you say? Maybe, but we're getting really hypothetical here, and in any case, macro-optimization can be relied on to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, but that's an apples to oranges comparison. Getting a haircut takes actual time, and probably even money. I agree it is such a microoptimization that it doesn't really matter. But it also doesn't *cost* us anything. if I can choose to go left or right, and the distance is the same, the terrain is the same, *everything* is the same, except that the left path has some marginal microscopic benefit, why not go left? You're right, it's not an impressive argument. But when the cost is literally zero, I see no reason to prefer the less optimal route.

Comment: I wasn't really disagreeing with you.  I agree that you still shouldn't care which is used, but consistency of style is important.  If two options are equally readable, you might as well chose the style that saves you three clock cycles.  If the sun is shining, or you feel `while(1)` is more descriptive than `for(;;)`, then use it, regardless of the lost clock cycles.  Even if that segment of code proves problematic, it probably won't be because of the type of loop you chose.  By similar logic, I always use `i++` in my own code because it makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: x43 speed-up?  Try CUDA.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: For the record I can seldom bring myself to write ++i in any case ;-); just too ugly!  And if you called a variable i and it was not a plain `int`, there are probably greater coding style issues!

Comment: @Clifford: I'm in violent agreement. I'm also really boring because I haven't found a humorous way to point out how amazing it is that hardware engineers knock their brains out making the machines faster and cheaper, while we coders, rather than eliminating unnecessary cycles, say "Why bother? Just throw more hardware at it." I have a mental image of a finely-bred race horse lugging a 400-lb jockey, or circling the track 10 times when once would do, or taking major detours.

Comment: With pre and post increment you **have** to care which one is used.  The difference will change program function, not merely performance.  If one of them "doesn't make sense" to you, then by all means avoid it.  In that case, better switch to `foo = foo + 1;` and keep it in a separate statement.  (And, to be safe, don't even think of using the trinary operator `?:`) Of course, this implies the preferred infinite loop form: `for(unsigned int i=0; i<0; i = i + 1);`

Answer (score 4):

The "forever" loop is popular in embedded systems as a background loop. Some people implement it as:

```
for (; ;)
{
 // Stuff done in background loop
}
```

And sometimes it is implemented as:

```
while (TRUE /* or use 1 */)
{
 // Stuff done in background loop
}
```

And yet another implementation is:

```
do
{
 // Stuff done in background loop
} while (1 /* or TRUE */);
```

An optimizing compiler should generate the same or similar assembly code for these fragments.  One important note:  the execution time for the loops is not a big concern since these loops go on forever, and more time is spent in the processing section.

Comment: If a compiler generates different code for those, it's time to ditch the compiler and get one from the last two decades.

Comment: "the execution time for the loops is not a big concern since these loops go on forever" -- that sounds so wrong to me..

Comment: @Blindy -- because it is wrong, what's of concern is the fraction of runtime spent processing looping logic, or the amount of looping logic per unit of useful work, neither of which are helped by the loop being infinite

Answer (score 4):

```
for(;;Sleep(50))
{
    // Lots of code
}
```

Is a clearer than:

```
while(true)
{
    // Lots of code
    Sleep(50);
}
```

Not that this applies if you aren't using `Sleep()`.

Comment: There is nothing clean about calling a function like sleep inside of a for loop like that

Comment: This is not equivalent. When there is a `continue` in the loop, the `for` loop sleeps but not the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4):

The most important reason to use "for(;;)" is the fear of using "while(TRUE)" when you do exploratory programming. It's easier to control the amount of repetitions with "for", and also, easier to convert the "for" loop into an infinite.

For example, if you are constructing a recursive function, you can limit the amount of calls to the function before converting into an infinite loop.

```
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) recursiveFunction(oneParam);
```

When I'm sure of my function, then I convert it to an infinite loop:

```
    for(;;) recursiveFunction(oneParam);
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume while(true) is more readable than for(;;) -- **its look like programmer misses something in for loop** :)

Comment: I care about speed. Especially if there is an optimization which will affect my code infinite times.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, it does not matter at all from a technical view. Some people think one is more readable than the other, and they have different opinions about which it is.

To me, that's basically just nitpicking, because any C programmer should be able to **instantly** recognize both `while(1)` and `for(;;)` as infinite loops.

Your define will not work. However, you CAN (but shouldn't) do this:

```
#define repeat for(;;)

int main(void)
{
    repeat {
        puts("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

But really, DON'T do things like that...