# What do parameter declarations between function declaration and bracket mean?

Tags: c

What's the difference between this declaration:

```
void 
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    // ...
}
```

from this?

```
void 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Does the top one even compile? (sorry, no access to C compiler at the moment)

Comment: Welp, I had never seen that before. Thanks for sharing this :)

Comment: That just good old pre-standard/K&R C. Nothing to see here..

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi

Comment: +1, I learned something from this question.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks: It used to, at least. A long time ago.

Comment: Known as "obsolete forms of function definitions" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efx873ys.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a different notation style that was used in C at its beginning called the KR Notation (for Kernighan and Ritchie, C's designers). The well known C notation style that is used today follows the ANSI standard.

Here's link to a Wikipedia article describing the KR notation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C#K.26R_C