# Passing variable through functions

Tags: c

How would I pass a variable from one function to another in C? For example I want to pass the `sumOfDice` from function roll and use `sumOfDice` for the `passLine` function: Here is my code:

```
    int roll()
   {
    int dieRollOne = (random()%6) + 1; 
    int dieRollTwo = (random()%6) + 1;

    printf("On Dice One, you rolled a: %d\n", dieRollOne);
    printf("On Dice Two, you rolled a: %d\n", dieRollTwo);

    int sumOfDice = dieRollOne + dieRollTwo;
    printf("The sum of you Dice is: %d\n", sumOfDice);
    return sumOfDice
  }
int passLine(int sumOfDice)
{
       // other code
       printf("the sum of dice is: %d\n", sumOfDice);
}
```

I would have used global variable for `sumOfDice`, but we are not allowed to. Would I have to pass with asterisk, like: `int *num;`

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: this is  a homework project to create a game of craps. I am just stuck on how to pass variables because I'm still learning how to code in C from java

Comment: You can only pass values between a function, and the function that called it. (In both directions)

Comment: Your code (As posted) doesn't have a `main()` function (entry point).
(As with Java), your program needs to have an entry point.  As it is, we cannot see where you are calling **either**of these functions!

Comment: I did not put a main function on this post because I thought it was irrelevant. I just wanted to know how to pass a function without using the main function.  So do I call the passLine function from the main and pass in roll?

Comment: In order to pass `sumOfDice` to `passLine`, you have to call `passLine` within the `roll` function passing `sumOfDice` as the parameter. There is *NO* reason the parameter name need be `sumOfDice` (e.g. `int passLine(int foo)` is fine). Then in `roll` , you simply call `passLine (sumOfDice);` which passes `sumOfDice` to `passLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nasim, this is one of the most fundamental concepts in C. It should be well-explained in any C book/tutorial you use. That said, everybody needs to learn somewhere. In order to pass values to/from a function, you start with the declaration of a function.

A function in C may receive any number of *parameters* but may only return a single value (or no value at all). A function requires those parameters specified in its *parameter list*. A function *declaration* takes the form of:

```
type name (parameter list);
```

The *type* is the *return type* for the function (or `void`). The *parameter list* contains the *type* of variables that are passed to the function. While you will normally see a parameter list in a *declaration* that contains both the *type* and *name*, only the *type* is required in the *declaration*. A function *definition* provides the function code and the function return. The parameter list for a function *definition* will contain both the *type* and *name* of the parameters passed.

(note: you may see old K&R function definitions without any *type* relying on the fact that the default type is `int`. That type definition/parameter list is obsolete. see [**Function declaration: K&R vs ANSI**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi))

Now that you have had a *Cliff's-notes* version of how to declare/define a function, a short example should illustrate passing/returning values to and from a function. This first example shows the function definitions that precede the `main` function. In this case no separate *declaration* is required:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bar (int x) {
    return x + 5;
}

int foo (int a) {
    return bar(a);
}

int main (void) {

    int n = 5;
    printf ("\n n = %d, foo(%d) = %d\n\n", n, n, foo(n));

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** function `bar` is placed *before* function `foo` because function `foo` relies on `bar`. A function must *always* have at minimum a *declaration* before it is *called*.)

Another example showing the common use of providing function *declarations* before `main` with the function *definitions* below would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (int);
int bar (int);

int main (void) {

    int n = 5;
    printf ("\n n = %d, foo(%d) = %d\n\n", n, n, foo(n));

    return 0;
}

int foo (int a) {
    return bar(a);
}

int bar (int x) {
    return x + 5;
}
```

(**note:** even though the function `foo` is *defined* before `bar` here, there is no problem. Why? Because `bar` is *declared* (at the top) before `foo` is called. **also note:** the declaration are shown with the *type* only, just to emphasize a point, you will normally see `int foo (int a);` and `int bar (int x);` as the *declarations*.)

**Use/Output**

The output of both is:

```
$ ./bin/func_pass_param

 n = 5, foo(5) = 10
```

I hope this has cleared up some of the basics for you. If not, you can ask further, but you are far better served finding a good C book or tutorial and *learning* the language (at least the basics) before you attempt to compile and run a program -- it will take you far less time in the long run.