# Why does a variable of a function declared outside its function definition doesn't throw an error?

Tags: c, syntax, kernighan-and-ritchie, function-definition

Why is this Code with integer declaration in the middle of nowhere (in-between function definition), not throwing an error?

1) Why is it syntactically correct.
2) What is the use of doing so.?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>  
void func(int, int);
int main()
{
     int a, b;
     a = 10;
     b = 20;
     func(a, b);

     return 0;
}
void func(i, j)
int i,j;                  //why does this doesn't throw error.
{
     printf("a = i = %d\nb = j = %d\n", i, j);
}
```

Comment: As answered below, it's syntactically correct because it is valid -- it's the original way things were done. There isn't any use of using this syntax now though unless you happen to be using a K&R style compiler that does not support ANSI C.

Comment: And don't **EVER** provide a prototype for a function defined in K&R style.  To find out why, change `int` to `char` in your function prototype and also in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - K&R style.

In your code

```
void func(i, j)
int i,j; {
```

does not throw an error, because it *was* a (*the only*) valid syntax, once upon a time.

Currently it is ***not invalid***, but not used anymore.

You can read more about [K&R style syntax here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3092006/2173917), if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
void func(i, j)
int i,j; //declare types of arguments
{
  //function body
}
```

is called the [K&R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi) syntax. It's obsolete but still used in some C projects like `bash`.