# What is this bizarre function declaration syntax?

Tags: c, syntax, arguments

I found this in a legacy D-ISAM implementation at my current company (*yes, they are still using D-ISAM, and it kills me every day*). In all my years of programming in C-like languages, I've never seen function arguments laid out in this way:

```
int isborlok( fd,mode,len,off )
int fd;
int mode;       
U32 len;
U32 off;
{
  //...
}
```

While I understand the syntax, it leaves me wondering:

- Does this syntax have a name (to differentiate it from regular inline type-declared arguments)?
- Is some sort of compiler specific syntax sugar or if it is part of an official C specification?

This is compiling under Visual Studio 2005. The header of the file indicates the code was created in 1988 (incidentally, the year I was born!).

Comment: That's K&R syntax, indicated by the fact that it predates C90. It's deprecated in C99.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi might help