# C++11 syntax 'type var : var' is called 'range-based for'

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

In an example regarding `std::codecvt` seen on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt, there was this syntax:

**`for (char16_t c : str16)`**

knowing that str16 is a variable (l-value) `std::u16string str16`.

What does it mean?
That's what I call `type var : var` in the title.

---

PS: Is there a topic referencing all the particular syntax types? The rare ones?

Recently I saw:

```
int ackermann(m,n)
int m,n; 
{
    // function definition
}
```

Comment: That is the syntax for a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: The syntax shown in your example is ancient (as in `int ackermann(m,n)
int m,n; `), forget it honestly ( unless you're working with legacy code from the 80's/90's ). `for (char16_t c : str16)` is a range based for loop, it can be thought of as for each char16_t c in str16, in the definition of the loop `c` will be the current char.

Comment: That's a range-based for loop

Comment: I have made researches. But, I was confronting a syntax, I didn't add any keywords  giving me clues. My intuition tells me it is a `type var : var` not a  `range-based for`. Plus, I tagged it  `c++ ` not  `c++11 `, so this question has its place here.

Comment: For a good reference on the syntax of various language constructs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language . From there, you can click on link labelled range-for to find the explanation for the syntax you are asking about.

Comment: `type var : var` is the syntax for a range based for loop, the syntax didn't exist in the standard pre C++11, it means create a new object of `type` and copy the current object to it. Also, if you've found code using ye'olde K&R syntax in the same code base as range based for loop syntax, then something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @george No it wasn't in the same code. It was to point out how it's difficult for me to find what a syntax mean, especially when old or deprecated. K&R and `range-based for` weren't mixed at all… :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/7134/side-by-side-comparisons-of-classic-c-examples-solved-via-c-vs-c11-vs-c1/23914/looping-through-a-container#t=201611281350181849843, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/7841/iteration#t=201611281350524510488

Comment: If you find my question very unpleasant or not useful, I can remove it. Not worth to make negative votes, it's also making my reputation going down, it's not fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (char16_t c : str16)
```

The syntax above defines a range-based for loop (introduced in C++11). It essentially says:

> Loop over each character in `str16`, copy the character into a variable called `c` and allow me to use it.

For example:

```
for (char16_t c : str16)
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Your second example is a K&R-style C function definition, and is obsolete. See here for more information: [Function declaration: K&R vs ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi#3092074)

Comment: Thanks. It was also useful to have a link to the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for like given by @starl1qgt

Answer (score 0):

This is called [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). This is very common idiom since C++11 for traversing whole container.

Answer (score 0):

`for (char16_t c : str16)` is the new ranged-for loop syntax introduced in C++11, plenty of examples and explanations around.

Comment: While mostly true (except for "new"), this answer is not useful, especially with the more helpful other answers

Comment: What do you mean by  "except for new"? It's new in C++11.

Comment: I suppose you could say it _was_ new in C++11. Which is 5 (nearly 6) years old. And the syntax existed as a language extension in many compilers long before that.