# c and c++ function declaration & definition : specifying data type

Tags: c++, c, function, visual-c++

I am working on porting c code to c++. The below C program compiles successfully. But in c++, it throws an error. I know its really basic thing. I've more than 100 functions declared in this way. Is there any flag we can add to compile successfully instead of modifying all the functions.

- OS: Windows
- IDE: Visual Studio

```
int sum(m,n)
int m,n;
{
    return m+n;
}
```

Comment: You might look at some *"reformater"* tools to automatise the process. I don't know if *clang-tidy*/*clang-format* supports that notation though.

Answer (score 5):

This is very old style C. Nobody should have been using this for the last 30 years. You can't compile this with a C++ compiler. There are no compiler flags whatsoever for this, at least in the compilers I'm aware of (clang, gcc, microsoft compilers).

You should transform all functions that have the form

```
int sum(m,n)
int m,n;
{
    return m+n;
}
```

int to the form

```
int sum(int m, int n)
{
    return m+n;
}
```

If you have 100 functions it should be doable.
But there may be many other problems because C++ is not an exact superset of C.

This SO article may be interesting for you: [Function declaration: K&R vs ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi)

Comment: I think you have a small typo: `int sum(int m, _int_ n)`. But +1 for teaching me about K&R function declaration style. :)