# Is there a reason why declarations and assignments of variables are on different lines in K&R?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

I'm starting to read *The C Programming Language*, and I noticed that the declarations of variables and the assignment of them are on different lines. For example, from page 16:

```
int c;
c = getchar();
```

Is there a reason why `int c = getchar();` is not written (in general, why assignment is not on the same line as declaration)? It seems to work fine when I run it instead of the former.

Comment: It's just the style of the author, there's no technical difference.

Comment: That's an older style. Variables used to be declared at the start of the scope block in which they were used. Now variables are declared when and where they are needed.

Comment: Actually, this is the way that C used to be written. Back in the days before standardization, some C compilers required you to declare variables on a different line than the definition.

Comment: Actually, the original K&R C spec had the variable declarations before the curly brackets. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi) for more info.

Comment: @GuyMarino That's only for the function parameters, not local variables.

Comment: Be aware that if you put a `static` before your variable definitions, these 2 versions will have different meaning.

Comment: Aside from the history, note that initialization in a declaration is **not** assignment. It shares some appearance with an assignment (like the `=`), and it shares some semantics with an assignment (like conversion to the target type), but it has some differences. `static int x = 3;` will store `3` in `x` only once, when `x` is created at the beginning of program execution, not each time the definition is reached during execution. And `int *p = &x;` puts `&x` in `p`, not in `*p`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are reading second edition of the book, it is mentioned on page 86.

> In effect, initializations of automatic variables are just shorthand for assignment statements. Which form to prefer is largely a matter of taste. We have generally used explicit assignments, because initializers in declarations are harder to see and further away from the point of use.

Comment: Note that the last argument no longer holds - since C99 declarations can occur at first point of use (or rather at the minimal necessary scope of use).  It was never a good idea to leave a variable unitialised in any case - even if you never use the value before reassigning it.  It explains the authors' thinking, but does not excuse it - even if they did invent the language!

Answer (score 3):

It was once the case in C that you could only declare variables at the start of a block (immediately after the `{`). This was because the compiler technology was just not up to the task of arbitrarily positioned variable declarations yet.

I'm pretty sure that originally you couldn't initialize a variable with a function call early on, but by the time the writing of K&R that was already gone. But old habits stick around long after they're needed, so that's what it was.

In C '99 and newer, variable declarations can go anywhere statements can, and also in the initialization step of a `for` loop.

Comment: C 1990 required declarations to be only at the start of a compound statement (C 1990 6.6.2). Initializers did not have to be constant expressions except for static objects or aggregates or unions (6.5.7). C 1999 allowed them to be anywhere (C 1999 6.8.2). Initializations are older; they were in K&R first edition, so that’s 1978.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I briefly had access to older C than K&R C and that's what I'm talking about "early on".

Comment: My comment does not say that initializations were not in C or that you did not have access. It provides additional information you could edit into the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I see.

Answer (score 1):

The original version of the C programming language did not support the newer syntax.  Later editions of the book added some of the new syntaxes, but there have been new versions of C since the last edition of the book, so not all of them are there even in the last edition.