# What is the difference between for(;;) and while(1)?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “for(;;)”  faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

I was wondering what is the difference between `for(;;)` and `while(1)` when both perform same function? Will there be any difference of speed of compilation

Comment: How can you close a __C++ best-practice__ question pointing to __C# best-practice__ answers? Sorry, but this is absurd. Voted to re-open.

Comment: will there be any difference in the compilation speed!!generally programmers are said to use while rather than for

Comment: @sbi: I think the confusion results from the answers being virtually equivalent between the two questions. But I agree, this *is* a distinctly different question.

Comment: If anything, this is a more appropriate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it

Comment: @Cody: It is indeed. Is it an _exact_ duplicate? Shall we close this one pointing to it? (And: Even if the answers to best-practice syntax questions are virtually equivalent between languages, _best practice syntax_ IMO still warrants language-specific questions. And my answer doesn't even apply to C#, since it doesn't have as many compilers as C++ has.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference with these is that many compilers will warn about `while(true)` ("constant expression used as loop expression"), while none I know of warn about `for(;;)`.

They should generate the same code, though.

Comment: ...which seems like a big plus for `for(;;)`, since no-one really writes either `while(true)` or `for(;;)` by accident.

Comment: @sgolodetz: I thought my answer would imply which one I prefer.

Comment: I guess yup. Sorry, prob didn't need to stick my oar in there...

Answer (score 9):

no functional difference at all, just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 8):

With `for`, you can do this:

```
#define ever (; ;) // note the two happy faces? ;)

for ever { ... }   // endless loop
```

Which is not possible with `while`.

Comment: +1 for creativity, yes. However, you can write: #define forever (1)
    while forever {...}

Comment: That's just... *such* a bad idea. Words cannot describe.

Comment: Could one not `#define forever for(; ;)` and then `forever{ --age }`...

Answer (score 6):

- Both will cause infinite loop unless
  `break` is called explicitly.
- Personally I prefer while(1), it's
  more readable

Comment: Definitely a matter of taste; I find `for(;;)` more readable.

Comment: +1 for (;;) {works in java and javascript as well)

Answer (score 4):

No difference. I prefer the latter.

Comment: will there be any speed difference during the time of compilation..another thing saurav did u see my other quwstion the automatic gear shift i,m looking forward to u ans that question!!

Comment: @abhinav : No the machine code generate would most probably be same in both the cases. As far as I can see you have already accepted an answer to that question.

Comment: @saurav i accepted the answer but i'm still looking forward to a different approach..

Comment: @saurav can you plz tell me which book should i refer for c++ i'm doin engg 1st year and i don't have much idea bout the lang

Comment: @abhinav : Read C++ Primer by Stan Lippman.

Answer (score 4):

6 of one, 110 of the other.

The latter appears more concise.

Answer (score 0):

No difference, unless you want to make use some kind counter later as below.

```
for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
   // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same in C++. However, your post is tagged with `c#` and `c++`.

If you're using C#, you'll need to use `while (true) {...}`. Personally, I prefer the same in C++: numbers are used only when dealing with... well, numbers! When dealing with boolean values, `true` and `false` are used instead.

Answer (score 0):

They both defines the exact same functional behavior and produce exactly the same IL code from C#.

Answer (score -1):

I'm old-school, I still do the following:

```
#define TRUE 1  
#define FALSE 0  
while (TRUE) { /*--do something, mutley--* }
```

Comment: So **you're** the one... >_<