# Which infinite loop is preferable to use

Tags: java, c++, c, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “for(;;)” faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

I been reading a programming book(java) there the author uses `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`. This thing realy starts to annoy me so I thought I should check which is the best to use and if there are any diffrences. Here are the possible infinite loops:

```
for(;;){

}

while(true){

}

do{

}while(true)
```

- Which is preferble to use?
- Is there any diffrences in preformance (like you have to test if true is true in the while case) or are they compiled to the same thing?

Comment: My guess would be that most programmers would recognise the intent of `while(true)` without having to glance twice; so for the sake of keeping to the principle of least confusion, I'd choose that one personally.  Ultimately I think it's little more than a style choice really.

Comment: You forgot one:

    start:
    int nop = 1+1;
    break start;

Comment: `#define ever ;;`
`for(ever)`

Comment: On some compilers while(true) raises a compilation warning (constant condition), while for(;;) doesn't. Therefore if you need a clean C++ build without any warning you may be forced to use for(;;)

Comment: @Paolo : +1, I'm glad someone finally mentioned that.

Answer (score 6):

They are compiled to the same thing, and are merely a matter of style. Older programmers may recognize `for(;;)`, but I would probably just use `while(true)`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with older; people have been divided between `for(;;)` and `while (1)` since the dawn of C.

Comment: @Kaz: `while (1)` is not the same thing as `while (true)` - the first will not work for Java.

Comment: That is correct, but I hope you can appreciate that I could not have written "people have been divided between `for(;;)` and `while (true)` since the dawn of C".

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is just a matter of style and I prefer `while(true)` since the intent is clear straight away. `for(;;)` just doesn't say anything to me.

Comment: `while(true)` is a kind of nonsense. It's testing a condition that can never change. A true infinite loop has no condition, and `for(;;)` expresses exactly that, by design.

Comment: Holy bike shed batman! I like the idea of testing a condition that can never change because it's guaranteed to execute infinitely.

Comment: You might like the MIPS instruction set. In MIPS, there is a register R0 which is read-only and permanently holds a zero. Furthermore, the unconditional branch instruction B <addr> is just a macro for a "BEQ R0, R0, <addr>": branch if the zero register is equal to itself.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, measure.

If nothing else, code up all three versions and look at the generated assembly for each of them.  Unless the compiler is *very* stupid, I will bet real money it will generate the exact same code for all three.

**EDIT**

FWIW, gcc generates the same code for all three (at least in the dead simple cases that I wrote).  `while(true)` is computable at compile time; there's no *need* to perform a test, just hardcode a jump back to the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

They should be identical performance-wise, but even if they aren't, speed doesn't matter as nuch as readability. The best method is the one that will be soonest recognized as an infinite loop by anyone that looks at the code. I would tend toward `while (true)` since it the most basic case, but that depends on who is looking at the code.

Comment: Hope you wouldn't sacrifice speed over readability on say i.e. an encoder.

Comment: 'Encoder' is a broad term. The situations where performance is that critical are few and far between.