# while(true) / while(1) vs. for(;;)

Tags: c#, c++, c, loops, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for ( ; ; ) or while ( true ) - Which is the Correct C# Infinite Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-sharp-infinite-loop)
>   [Why choosing for (;;){} over while(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545237/why-choosing-for-over-while1)

What's the difference between `while(true)`, `while(1)`, and `for(;;)`? They all are infinite loops in languages like C# and C/C++. But is one better than the other one? Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-sharp-infinite-loop?rq=1. Note the answer which demonstrates that the c# compiler will turn `for` into `while`.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545237/why-choosing-for-over-while1 for C++.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-sharp-infinite-loop) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288856/when-implementing-an-infinite-loop-is-there-a-difference-in-using-while1-vs-f) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505755/best-infinite-loop) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114122/which-infinite-loop-is-preferable-to-use).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference once the program is compiled.

Here are some excerpts from three C programs and the corresponding generated assembly for all of them.

Let's try the `for` loop first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   for(;;)
      printf("This is a loop\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Now we will try the `while` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   while(1)
      printf("This is a loop\n");
   return 0;
}
```

A terrible solution, the `goto` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   alpha:
      printf("This is a loop\n");
      goto alpha;
   return 0;
}
```

Now, if we examine the generated assemblies, using the command `gcc -S loop.c`, they all look like this (I didn't see any reason to post them separately, since they are identical):

```
   .file "loop.c"
   .section .rodata
.LC0:
   .string  "This is a loop"
   .text
.globl main
   .type main, @function
main:
   leal  4(%esp), %ecx
   andl  $-16, %esp
   pushl -4(%ecx)
   pushl %ebp
   movl  %esp, %ebp
   pushl %ecx
   subl  $4, %esp
.L2:
   movl  $.LC0, (%esp)
   call  puts
   jmp   .L2
   .size main, .-main
   .ident   "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)"
   .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

This part is the loop. It declares a label, copies the address to the string into a register, calls a routine called `puts`, and jumps back to the label:

```
.L2:
   movl  $.LC0, (%esp)
   call  puts
   jmp   .L2
```

Since they all do exactly the same thing, clearly there is no technical advantage of any of them (at least if you are using `gcc`).

However, people have opinions, and may favor one over the others for whatever reason. Since `for(;;)` is only seven characters long, it is easier to type (this is my preference). On the other hand, `while(1)` gives the illusion of a test which always evaluates to `true`, which some may find more intuitive. Only a few crazy people like the `goto` solution best.

Edit: Apparently some compilers might produce a warning for `while(1)` because the condition is always true, but such warnings can be easily disabled and have no effect on the generated assembly.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I guess you have a point. I was using `gcc`, which does not issue such warnings. Perhaps I'll have try it in Visual Studio. I used the generated assembly to back up my claim that all of those ways of creating infinite loops do exactly the same thing, as I feel that such claims should be backed up by hard evidence rather than pulled out of nowhere.

Comment: I've heard about cases where a compiler might warn about `while (1)` because the condition is always true, while it won't warn about `for (;;)` because there is no (explicit) condition.