# Why choosing for (;;){} over while(1)?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “for(;;)” faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

I see this

```
for (;;)
{
  // Some code here
}
```

quite often. But what benefits does it offer and why just not choose `while(1){}`?

Comment: Okay. I searched for it. But neither google nor Stackoverflow search function returned an adequate result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They produce identical code. There are a couple of reasons why you might prefer `for (;;)` but it is all just personal preference:

1. Some compilers will warn you about conditions that are always true. `for(;;)` will not have that problem.
2. `for (;;)` literally reads as "Just loop forever!", whereas `while (true)` still *appears* to have some kind of condition.

I say pick one and stick with it. It doesn't matter as long as you don't switch between them arbitrarily.

Comment: Personal opinion, but `for (;;)` literally reads as bad form to me, while `while(true)` literally reads as "Just loop forever!" They are completely identical in behavior and in assembly code produced by the compiler.

Comment: @DavidHammen Precisely! I was just giving a reason why `for (;;)` might be more common.

Answer (score 4):

This is the form of the *forever* loop that [Kernighan and Ritchie used in their book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)<sup>*</sup>. There is absolutely no other reason to prefer one form over the other.

<sup>*</sup> Section 3.5 on While and For loops, example number four.

Comment: It's 1 character smaller. And [Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) doesn't even have a while loop, so it's easier for Go programmers to understand?

Answer (score 3):

The two are equivalent and will most likely result in identical machine code. Choosing one over the other is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Not quite correct. They are (arguably) identical in effect, but not quite in the expressed meaning: One contains a "condition", the other doesn't.

Comment: @stakx: They both contain conditions: one is always true, and the other is, well, always true.

Answer (score 2):

It does not really matter - it is just personal preference.

I like `for(;;)` better because I think it underlines *loop forever* aspect.

Comment: And I think `while(true)` looks like a condition that will be `true` forever. :-)