# What is the feature to use for( ;; )?

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “for(;;)” faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

Found code with this for-loop.
 What exactly feature to use it insted of `while(true)` for example? Is it uses less memory ?

Comment: for (;;) is just an empty loop that reserves some space for more complex conditionals than while. Otherwise, not much benefit.

Comment: Compared with `while(true)`, `for(;;)` uses 4 bytes less memory on your hard drive.

Comment: @FredOverflow: What's more important is that some compilers (used to?) warn about `while(true)` ("constant expression in condition") but none I came across warned about `for(;;)`.

Comment: @sbi But I find `while(true)` way more readable.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Readability is in the eye of the beholder. `:)`

Comment: @sbi Right, you could `#define ever (;;)` and then `for ever` is the most readable ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`for(;;)` is functionally equivalent to `while(true)` but avoids a "conditional expression is constant" warning with some compilers (including MSVC's cl)

Comment: Surely `nmake` is not a compiler, is it?

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger clarified as `cl`

Comment: The compiler is called _MSVC_. `cl.exe` is just one of the command line tools (there's also `link.exe`, for example) coming with it. So, "including MSVC" should do.

Answer (score 3):

This construct has been popularized by Kernighan and Ritchie in their *C Programming Language* book (section 3.5)

> The for statement

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement
```

> If expr1 or expr3 is omitted, it is simply dropped from the expansion. If the test, expr2, is not present, it is taken as permanently true, so

```
for (;;) {
    ...
}
```

is an "infinite" loop, presumably to be broken by other means, such as a `break` or `return`.

There is absolutely no difference between `for(;;)` and `while(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{

}
```

Is always what I've used and what I've seen others use for a loop that has to be broken manually.

Some compilers are giving you wrnings that this while loom MAY be incorrect. But it is not.

The assembly code generated for both is exactly the same. No diferences.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, The use of loop depends on the requirement & based on that only we can decide when to use which one. Just check what @Luchian has asked, then you will come to know it.

**Secondly**, that clearly depends on the particular implementation of the interpreter/compiler of the specific language.

That said, theoretically, any sane implementation is likely to be able to implement one in terms of the other if it was faster so the difference should be negligible at most.