# How does this "for (;;)" syntax work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I came across a strange syntax for the `for` in an open source Javascript library.

```
for (;;) {
}
```

What does this even do? Can anyone answer?

Comment: Runs a for loop for ever and ever :)

Comment: [see the relevant section of ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's "loop forever" and it works the same in C, C++, C#, Java etc. You've got a `for` statement with

- no init step
- no termination check (=> continue forever)
- no end-of-loop step

Comment: You have nice answers: short and precise. May the upvotes and badges be with you. And thanks for that link to the java bouncy castle example, which I stole and turned into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's an infinite loop, just like `while(true)`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already pointed out, if will run forever, but you can still end the loop with `break`. Like:

```
for (;;) {
    if (condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
has a good breakdown of how javascript evaluates `for` loops:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

> **initialization**
>       An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable declaration. Typically used to initialize a counter variable. This
>   expression may optionally declare new variables with the var keyword.
>   These variables are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same
>   scope the for loop is in. The result of this expression is discarded.
>
> **condition**
>       An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional
>   test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true.
>   If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first
>   expression following the for construct.
>
> **final-expression**
>       An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to
>   update or increment the counter variable.
>
> **statement**
>       A statement that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the loop, use a block
>   statement ({ ... }) to group those statements.

Most relevant to this question is in the **condition** section:

> This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always
>   evaluates to true.

Comment: You can *and should* end the loop with `break` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple/empty `;` in many languages acts as a blank but true (and executable) statement.

Hence, in the for loop, all three *expressions* are true, always matched and hence, results in an infinite loop.

---

It has also been on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Use_as_infinite_loops). As per the wiki page

> This style is used instead of infinite `while(1)` loops to avoid a
>   warning in [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h.aspx).

---

The controlling expression of an `if` statement or `while` loop evaluates to a constant. If the controlling expression of a `while` loop is a constant because the loop will exit in the middle, consider replacing the while loop with a for loop. You can omit the initialization, termination test and loop increment of a **`for`** loop, which causes the loop to be infinite (like `while(1)`) and you can exit the loop from the body of the for statement.

Comment: `for` loops don't have "three conditions"

Answer (score 2):

This is valid for loop `for (;;) {}` if condition is not given in for loop its by default true. So loop run infinitely. same as `for (;1;) {}`

Additionally not only in Javascript its true in C, C# language also etc.

Read this: [Is “for(;;)” faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it) to know why some programmers may prefer `for (;;) {}` over simple `while(true){}` (interesting)

Answer (score 0):

It runs an infinite loops, because

Essentially, a for loop is a shortened version of another loop, with this syntax

```
for(a;b;c){
}
```

is

```
a;
while(b){

c;
}
```

so loops forever, since the b is empty, and  it has no increment operator to change anything. 
Basically, it's an infinite loop of nothingness.
EDIT: Apparently, the empty command evaluates to true.

Comment: this isn't quite right. If the `for` loop ran as the `while` loop does in your example, none of the contents would ever be executed. `b` would be `undefined` which would be falsey, and the body would never execute. It's a quirk of the language that allows `for (;;)` to execute similar to a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: Also, I assume you meant to write `for(a;b;c)` instead of with commas.