# Empty statements in for loop VS infinite while

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, compilation

I've noticed a strange statement while reading C code:

```
for (;;) {
    // some code
}
```

That is the first time I see this syntax but I assume this is equivalent to:

```
while(true) {
    // some code
}
```

The result is obviously the same (in terms of logic).

Then why is it written like that?
Is there a difference at compilation time?

Comment: AFAIK, both are same.

Comment: some oldtimers used to do `#define ever ;;` and then use it like `for(ever)`

Comment: It's the programmer's choice to use one or the other form. It's the same thing and the compiler will most likely generate exactly the same machine code.

Comment: Maybe 2nd statement be like more readable to people .

Comment: Duplicate: [Is “for(;;)” faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

Both of them works like the same!
If we follow the semantics of for loop
Then for loop works like this:

```
for(_INITIALIZATION;_CONDITIONN_CHECKING;_OPEARTION){
    //Some code Here
}
```

Now each of the terms inside the for loop are independent of each other.
So for(;;) means there is nothing condition  to break the loop.
Some other way of defining infinite for loops are

```
a)for(;;)
b)for(_INITIALIZATION;;)
c)for(;;operations)
d)for(_INITIALIZATION;;_OPERATIONS)
E)for(_INITIALIZATION;1;_OPERATIONS)
```

Comment: ok, I know that, but my question is : why did someone choose this statement rather than the more readable "infinite while loop" ?

Comment: @BlueMagma  Isn't that upto the programmer himself . IMHO it can't have any generalized or direct answer .

Comment: it is user specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the same, just somewhat semantically "more meaningful" for a reader than `while(true)`

Comment: In what way is it more meaningful ? I think the while(true) is more meaningful and easier to read

Comment: As for personally me, I prefer while(true) finding it more elegant. But formally one should agree that 'it's unconditional' looks more concise than 'its condition is always true' :)

Comment: @BlueMagma: I know at least one popular compiler emits a warning _"conditional expression is constant"_ for `while (true)`. I try to write code that compiles cleanly (without warnings).