# Can I make a StopWatch using the Sleep function?

Tags: c++, stopwatch

This is my code:

```
double sec = 0;

while (1)
{
    sec += 0.01;
    Sleep(10);
    cout << sec << endl;
}
```

I want to make a stopwatch. I used the `Sleep` function to increase variable every 10ms, but output variable doesn't match with the computer's stopwatch.

- Can you tell me a reason?
- and is there any other way to make a stopwatch?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: no idea what Sleep is, but it might be that it waits at minimum the given time. The rest of the code also needs time. How to solve: Use a timer which calls your function periodical .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting wrong value for Millisecond delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445592/getting-wrong-value-for-millisecond-delay)

Comment: [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) Please [edit] your question to include a working program, e.g. by including the `#include`s used by your program.

Comment: you have to use the sleep function properly.I have given complete sleep example solution in the link, [c++ sleep function guidelines][1]


  [1]: https://svsivan.blogspot.com/2020/07/sleep-function-c.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051948/why-is-stdcout-so-time-consuming 
"Replace << std::endl; with << '\n'. This will refrain from flushing the internal buffer of the C++ runtime to the operating system on every single line. It should result in a huge performance improvement."

Comment: You want to query current time at the beginning and before each sleep, and calculate the delay based on that. If you want to print a message every 10 ms, then your wakeups are x+0, x+10, x+20, x+30... ms. If current time is x+11, then you only need to sleep 9ms. If it's x+25, you only need to sleep 5 ms.

Comment: @shivcena this will not work by exactly the same reason the original attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @NileshSolanki If you don't flush the buffer, you don't see messages as they are sent to the output. You only see them when the system decides to flush. What good is a stopwatch that beeps 10 seconds after it stops because its internal buffer was not full enough to flush?

Comment: You should also know that a typical Windows console probably cannot print a line each 10 ms. There is not enough oomphs to scroll the buffer that fast.  You may want to print all output on the same line with `<< 'r' << std::flush` or something.